# Algorithm to find which polygon a point belongs to given the coordinate of a polygon

Tags: algorithm

The real life problem is something like this: Given the borders of different countries as a series of coordinate forming polygons, and given a point A with a longitude and a latitude, determine which country contains the point A.

A rough drawing of the problem looks something like this: 
[image: Schematic drawing]

Is there an algorithm that would allow me to determine which country the given point belongs to? We can assume that the country border are given as triples (longitude,latitude,ISO2).

Comment: Yes there is probably is. Would you like it in Java, C#, Python, MIPS, Binary? ... You must first make an attempt sir.

Comment: My thinking was to choose a band of width W and see if there are any borders south and north of my y-position. If there isn't then increase W until I find either a south or north coordinate. Then I do the same thing on the length to find a west or east boundary. If the n/s e/w pair belongs to the same country, then we've found the country.

Comment: There are some border points inside other country if intrapolation is taken as linear. So resolution could be an issue if intrapolation is linear.

Comment: @theblindprophet They asked for an algorithm. An algorithm doesn't require a programming language (or even a computer).

Comment: An attempt should have still been made, then he should specify pseudo code.

Comment: Google "point in polygon test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon), various methods can be used, which depend on the representation of the polygon. One possibility is to send a ray in a fixed direction from the point for which to decide containment and count the number of intersection with the polygon; if the number is even, the point is outside of the polygon and inside the polygon otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test would be to take a line starting from the query point going to infinity in some direction (say positive x). Then intersect it with all the line segments forming your polygon.

If you have an odd number of intersections then your point is inside the polygon. If you have an even number of intersections, then the point is outside.

This works for any non-self-intersecting polygon.